# How to react once to a change in two or more watched properties in vuejs

Tags: vuejs2

There are many use cases for this but the one I'm dealing with is as follows. I have a page with a table, and two data properties, "page" and "filters". When either of these two variables are updated I need to fetch results from the server again.

However, there is no way as far as I can see to watch two variables and react only once, especially in the complicated instance updating filters should reset page to zero.

```
javascript

data: {
  return {
    page: 0,
    filters: {
      searchText: '',
      date: ''
    }
  }
},
watch: {
  page (nv) {
    this.fetchAPI()
  },
  filters: {
    deep: true,
    handler (nv) {
      this.page = 0
      this.fetchAPI()
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  fetchAPI () {
    // fetch data via axios here
  }
}
```

If i update filters, its going to reset page to 0 and call fetchAPI() twice. However this seems like the most intuitive way to have a page with a table in it? filters should reset page to zero as you may be on page 500 and then your filters cause there to only be 1 page worth of results, and a change to either page or filters must call the api again.

Interested to see how others must be tackling this exact same problem reactively?

Comment: Why need to fetch data when only `page` changes? Seems like `page` is the page of the table?

Comment: Yeah page is the page of the table, so only showing 50-100 of 1000 rows for example

Comment: Make your `fetchAPI` a [throttled](https://underscorejs.org/#throttle) or [debounced](https://underscorejs.org/#debounce) function? In your case, you can just set the page to `0` when `filters` change as that will automatically call `fetchAPI` from `page`'s watch handler. So no need to call fetch in filter change explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Take into the rule - watchers are the "last hope". You must not use them until you have other ways.

In your case, you could use events. This way the problem will go by itself:

Add `@click="onPageChange"` event to the `page` button (or whatever do you use).

Add `@change="onFilterChange"` event to the `filter` component (or whatever do you use). You can also use `@click="onFilterChange"` with some additional code to detect changes. Still, I am pretty sure you must have something like `@change` on the `filter` component.

Then your code will look like:

```
data: {
  return {
    page: 0,
    filters: {
      searchText: '',
      date: ''
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  onPageChange () {
    this.fetchAPI()
  },
  onFilterChange () {
    this.page = 0
    this.fetchAPI()
  },
  fetchAPI () {
    // fetch data via axios here
  }
}
```

In this case, the `onFilterChange` will change the `page` data but will not trigger the `onPageChange` method. So your problem will not exist.

Comment: I could emit an onChange event from the filter component but honestly, id just watch the filter item in there and emit a change when the deep watcher detects a change. It seems like the whole point in vuejs is data reactivity so this approach watching all these individual events seems a bit old school and not the way vuejs and reactive programming intended to change things?

Comment: My filter component is really quite complex there are over 30 filters, this is why im trying to get it done by watching just one parent variable "filters" with the deep flag

Comment: You can add status on fetch API. So if fetching is in the "fetching" state then do not call it again. Also, if results are newer than 500 ms then do not fetch again. You need to add some code to the `fetchAPI` function and axious callbacks to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Since the filters object is really complicated and has many options i have decided to keep it on a watcher that triggers setting page to zero and reloading the api. I now solve the problem as stated below. The 'pauseWatcher' data variable is a bit messy and needing to disable it in nextTick seems unideal but its a small price to pay for not having to manually hook up each and every filters input (some of them are far more complex than one input, like a date filter between two dates) and have them each emit onChange events that trigger reloading the api. It seems sad Vuejs doesnt have a lifecycle hook where you can access data properties and perhaps route paramters and make final changes to them before the watchers and computed properties turn on.

```
data: {
  return {
    pauseWatcher: true,
    page: 0,
    filters: {
      searchText: '',
      date: ''
    }
  }
},
watch: {
  filters: {
    deep: true,
    handler (nv) {
      if (this.pauseWatcher) {
        return
      }
      this.page = 0
      this.fetchAPI()
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  fetchAPI () {
    // fetch data via axios here
  },
  goToPage(page) {
    this.page = page
    this.fetchAPI()
  },
  decodeFilters () {
    // decode filters from base64 URL string
  }
},
created () {
  this.pauseWatcher = true
  this.page = Number(this.$route.query.page) || 0
  this.filters = this.decodeFilters(this.$route.query.filters)
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.pauseWatcher = false
  })
}
```